# test button click in different tabs of browser at same time

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, web, automated-tests

I would like to test a button click event of a web page in different tabs of browser.

Let's say I have button named as Save Details in URL: http://example.org/UserDetails

Now I open the same URL in two different tabs in Chrome browser window.

I would like to click Save Details button in different tabs at same time. How is this possible ? Can I do this using selenium tool ?

Being a ASP.NET developer , I am new to testing tools. Any help would be great.

**Update:**

I want to simulate users clicking the same button in different browser or same browser different window at same time.

Comment: Can you do this manually ? Answer is NO. Selenium can't do so. At same time it is impossible , if you have only one browser instance .

Comment: Selenium is used for automating the tests you can do manually. I do not know of a way to click buttons in different tabs at exactly the same time, so I suppose there also is no way of automating that using selenium. Do you need it to be at the same time ?

Comment: Yes, you can. But it's not gonna be at the exactly same time, and it will be 2 windows, not 2 tabs. In order to do that, you just run two `chromedriver` instances. Then you can click both of them at the same time.

Comment: @cruisepandey , I can do this manually , but there is some delay in `clicks` while moving between tabs.

Comment: @Chai , yes same time.

Comment: @stom: you will have to launch two broswer instance at same time , then only you can accomplish this.

Comment: @cruisepandey , I can do that but still there will be delay in clicks when click in one window and move to another. I want the click at different window at same time.

Comment: @stom , you can manually click two buttons on different browser tabs with single mouse simultaneously?! I can hardly believe it...

Comment: @Andersson , No I can't , I meant I can click two buttons with some delay while switching the tabs.

Comment: @stom , In the same way Selenium will do. Your subject looks little confusing. Update your question and provide some code that you've tried already

Comment: @Andersson , It's simple,  I want to simulate users clicking the same button in different browser or same browser different window at same time.

Comment: @stom: Why are you keep saying at same time. It is not possible with single instance of any browser through automation and manually too.

Comment: @stom You're intention is still not clear. At the same time with some delay is simply not at the same time.

Comment: @cruisepandey , ok can I achieve this in different browser at same time ?

Comment: @stom : You can launch two different browser at same time and then you can perform same line of code , not sure if there would be delay for 1 or 2 sec though.

Comment: @cruisepandey , Thanks for the confirming that it is possible in two different windows. That's enough to move forward. And I can see in the answer posted it is possible in different windows. But I don't why the down votes ?

Comment: @stom : I have not down voted your question. No still it is not possible in two different windows. Good luck.

Comment: @cruisepandey , I meant why other's down voted. As answers says it is possible in two different windows of different browser. Thanks.

Comment: @stom : Because your question wasn't clear , You did not share any code that you have tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Selenium is just an FT tool and it can perform single operation just like humans at a time on a webelement in non parallel run. So, at the same time it cannot perform click operation on two different tabs in same browser window.

For your use case, you need to depend on any other framework like TestNG along with selenium. TestNG has parallel run feature which allows you to trigger multiple test case at the same time. So, in your scenario, the same test case needs to be defined twice or can be duplicated and include both the test case in Testng.xml from where execution triggers. And also ensure that you include below attributes in testng.xml

```
<suite name="TestSuite" thread-count="2" parallel="methods" >
```

Thread-count - number of instances which you wish to open

Parllel - Indicates that the run should be parllel

In this run, there will be 2 browsers invoked at same time and two test cases(duplicated) will be executed in each browser. **It cannot execute in two different tabs, it will be in two different windows**

And also please note that it may not be accurate and there may be a difference of fraction of seconds due to network latency and machine performance

Comment: Glad to know it is possible in  two different windows. As a developer it would take some of time to set up selenium and TestNG . I will look at this later. Thanks for the answer though. Appreciate.